# Deserialize JSON Object .Net

Tags: .net, json, javascriptserializer

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON object:

```
"{\"results\":[{\"isError\":true,\"result\":null,\"messages\":[{\"type\":0,\"text\":\"Legal Entity is required when a Cost Center Code is specified: External Code 1 = cc3f25a7-0e8a-4e1c-8e18-c83c520ff3d7;\"}]}],\"isError\":true,\"sessionId\":null,\"tk\":null,\"tp\":null}"
```

I have the following classes:
[DataContract]

```
public class BigCenterResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "isError")]
    public bool IsError { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "sessionId")]
    public string SessionID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public List<Result> Responses { get; set; } 

}

[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "isError")]
    public bool IsError { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="messages")]
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }

}
```

And the following implementation:

```
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize<BigCenterResponse>(resp);
        obj.Responses = serializer.Deserialize<List<Result>>(resp);
        return obj;
    }
```

I am able to get the IsError set properly, but the Responses doesn't get filled. I have tried just Deserializing the BigCenterResponse and trying to deserialize the result section separately (as shown above). Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptSerializer doesn't use `DataMember`,  `DataContract` attributes.  But it is case insensitive.  So no difference between `public int type { get; set; }` and `public int Type { get; set; }`

---

```
public class Message
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class BigCenterResponse
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```